# How to fix 'OSError: [Errno 22] invalid argument' datetime Windows 10

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pandas, datetime, operating-system

I am working on a problem statement where I have to represent wrong data transmission occurred per hour. I am referring to https://www.kaggle.com/gpsaikrishna/credit-card-fraud-detection-smote-deep-learning 
for data representation purpose only.

I tried to put the data in my working directory. Still getting OS Error. My system's date and time are on auto-update with disabled daylight saving time. And is formatted as 
Time: 24 hours; HH: mm and 
Date: DD-MM-YYYY

Below is the code I'm trying to run on my system form the Kaggle kernel

```
def convert_totime(seconds):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds);

timeAnalysis = data[['Time', 'Amount', 'Class']].copy()
timeAnalysis['datetime'] = timeAnalysis.Time.apply(convert_totime)
timeDelta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.now()
# As the max time is 172792 seconds and 172792 / (60*60) is about 48 hrs so we only have data for 2 days so only 
# plotting data against hours make sense
timeAnalysis['hour of the day'] = timeAnalysis.datetime + timeDelta
timeAnalysis['hour of the day'] = timeAnalysis['hour of the day'].dt.hour
timeAnalysisGrouped = timeAnalysis.groupby(['Class', 'hour of the day'])['Amount'].count()
```

I am getting an error as

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-77-002a1f9a93fc> in <module>()
      3 
      4 timeAnalysis = data[['Time', 'Amount', 'Class']].copy()
----> 5 timeAnalysis['datetime'] = timeAnalysis.Time.apply(convert_totime)
      6 timeDelta = datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.datetime.now()
      7 # As the max time is 172792 seconds and 172792 / (60*60) is about 48 hrs so we only have data for 2 days so only

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3190             else:
   3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3193 
   3194         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-77-002a1f9a93fc> in convert_totime(seconds)
      1 def convert_totime(seconds):
----> 2     return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds);
      3 
      4 timeAnalysis = data[['Time', 'Amount', 'Class']].copy()
      5 timeAnalysis['datetime'] = timeAnalysis.Time.apply(convert_totime)

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I am expecting graph for the number of fraud transaction by using code below:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
fraudTransactions = timeAnalysisGrouped[1].copy()
fraudTransactions.name = 'Number of transactions'
fraudTransactions.plot.bar(title = 'Number of fraud credit card transactions per hour', legend = True)
```

Comment: Refer this https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp
and check if you have used the function correctly.

Comment: Yes, the function is called correctly in the code for `datetime`

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried `.map` in place of `.apply`. Apply passes `Series` objects to the function argument, not the elements itself. So in other words, you normally use it in case you work with "vectorized" functions.

Your function works with the single vectors, not with series and that's the problem with your code.

So you could try:

```
timeAnalysis.Time.map(convert_totime)
```

That should fix your main problem. Additionally you can also check, if you can directly work with more native pandas datatypes. The most convenient way to do a type conversion. If you haven't tried already, you could check if your datetime values are correctly parsed with the builtin `numpy` logic like this:

```
timeAnalysis.Time.astype('datetime64')
```

Alternatively you can also use `pandas.to_datetime` in your function like this:

```
def convert_totime(series):
    return pd.to_datetime(series)
```

If the values you want to convert are integers, that should be interpreted as seconds, you need to pass `unit='s'` to `to_datetime`.
If the values are presented in a string format, you probably need to use `format=` with the appropriate format string. See here for more info about the function: [Description of pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: As you said i replaced `.apply` with `.map` . No changes still getting the same error.

Comment: Then I think the format of your column is not supported. Please check the above code, if it solves the problem.

Comment: `timeAnalysis.Time.astype('datetime64')` the length of the data is 284807 all the values contain same epoch 1970-01-01 just that there is an increase in nanoseconds.

Comment: I replaced `def convert_totime(seconds):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds);` with what you suggested. replaced `.apply` with `.map`. I just got one bar at time interval `18`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it would help if you could provide some test data. Otherwise it is just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_totime(series):
    return pd.to_datetime(series, unit='s')

timeAnalysis.Time.apply(convert_totime)
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.